# How can I review code that a team member made today?

Tags: git, gitlab

Here's the situation:

We are a front-end team. Our team use Gitlab as Git-repository manager. We use gitflow as our git workflow.

We do a code review when a feature is finished and will be merged into develop branch. However, I found that the changes are always too big. Sometimes there can be 15-20 file changes and hundreds of lines of code changes in a merge request. That makes reviewing code like hell.

Is there a way to pick out code changes of a team member made today, so that we can review every day in incremental way?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking this suggests a problem with your team's git-workflow. The philosophy of git commits is for them to be small and address one specific thing.

So, you run into the problem you describe if people use git with a "save my work at the end of the day/week and upload it to the server" mentality.

Conversely, the team should try and make small atomic commits often. This could still mean that a commit is large, but then it should contain a message describing the changes. That should then assist you figuring out the changes in the files affected by this commit. Once you are done, move to the next commit. Rinse, repeat.

Comment: Our commits are not large, but there can be many commits in a merge request.That makes a merge request large.We do code review on a merge request. So I think doing it everyday might be a good frequency? but I can't figure out how to do  that.